# How do you find a relation between several functions?

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose you have a set of trigonometric functions, which appear unrelated, however they have some conserved properties.

What are the most common operations to find out a relationship between them?

My suggestion is to determine if their $n^{th}$ derivatives are similar to one another. However, I am not sure.

Take for example $\cos(2x)$, $\cos(20x)$, $\sin(2x)+1$:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Evidently, they all intersect at  $y=1$, and their slope differs  10-fold.

Then take this example over to a set of nonlinear functions, which are more messy in their wave-behaviour. How can the nonlinear terms that relate these nonlinear functions to one another be found?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  What does it mean to say that two or more functions "have some conserved properties"?

Comment: The example of such properties is the period, as given in the OP, and the intersection with the y-axis. Then you can even have a nonlinear relationship between them, which is "the conserved property"

Comment: If you know a given function is periodic with a given period, you can simply test the others.  And there are lots and lots of "non-linear" relations.

Comment: @lulu those "lots of nonlinear" relations, would be functions that one can find though some "ratio" or "relation" ? Here I am thinking that Sobolev space could be relevant.

Comment: Taking the derivatives does not really help.

Comment: Again, some "ratio" or "relation" is extremely vague.  If you have a functional form for your proposed non-linear relation, you should state what it is.  Otherwise...well, I expect that any two functions can be connected by some sort of relation.

Comment: It can be profoundly difficult to determine if a complex number, say $\exp (1)+\pi^2+\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 3}$ is transcendental, or algebraically independent of some other such expression.  And in that case we know the form of the relation we seek.  Your problem has to be much, much harder than that since you seem to have no idea what sort of relations you have in mind.

Comment: @lulu yes, indeed. However, a functional, as you say, can be used: such as the Fourier Transform, the Hilbert Transform, the Hankel transform etc. Then once transformed, the five functions may give a different relation to one another, and maybe much more evident.

Comment: I am saying that you need to clarify the type of relation you are considering and that even then it is likely that it will be difficult to determine that no such relation exists, given a particular starting collection.

Comment: I have only the functions, and I have no idea what they are related by, only that they have some relation to some nonlinear wave equation, such as the Korteweg de Vries equation.

Comment: @lulu how do "you clarify the type relation"? That is basically my original question in 5 words. Is NONLINEAR FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS book a good start?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, no.  As I've said, you need to clarify the sort of relation you are thinking of.  The class of "all possible non-linear relations" is simply too vast to be of any use.  Look at the functions in any way you can.  Try for linear dependence, that should be easy at least.  Use whatever you know about the way these functions were produced to try to predict potential patterns.  there is nothing like a universal approach here.

Comment: @lulu thanks. Sounds like a good start.

Answer (score 1):

de Moivre's formula combined to the Binomial formula are useful to find the expansion of $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$.

$$\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^n i^k\binom nk\cos^{n-k}(x)\sin^k(x).$$

You can sometimes eliminate $\cos$ or $\sin$ by means of $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$.